# Why this refer to window and not to anchor?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Inside an HTML table a link named lnkFullScreen calls the JavaScript function fullscreenmap. Inside the function I need to change the innertext of link but link variable refer to window insted of the link.

The page include prototype.js version 1.7.1

```js
function fullscreenmap(link) {
  $("tblMap").toggleClassName("overlay");
  if ($("tblMap").hasClassName("overlay"))
    link.innerText = "exit full screen";
  else
    link.innerText = "full screen mode";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.min.js" integrity="sha512-BfwTGy/vhB1IOMlnxjnHLDQFX9FAidk1uYzXB6JOj9adeMoKlO3Bi3rZGGOrYfCOhBMZggeXTBmmdkfscYOQ/w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<td class="thead" width="50%">
  <strong>Mappa</strong>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<a href="javascript:fullscreenmap(this)" id="linkFullScreen">full screen mode</a>
</td>
```

Comment: For me, it doesn't run at all for some reason. But I hadn't seen this syntax since for 5 years

Comment: Can be easily reproduced with `<a href="javascript:console.log(this)">Test</a>`. The best solution is probably not to use an anchor element if you're not using it as an anchor element. Use a `<button>` or something like that. (Which you can style just like a link.)

Comment: @Ivar you can keep the `<a>`. The thing is that you need to add a click handler, rather than try to use the `javascript:` "protocol" which browsers have tried to limit. I can't find a good dupe for it but in general `javascript:` is heavily restricted (works for bookmarklets but probably the only place where it's allowed).

Comment: @VLAZ You _can_, though I'm not a big fan of using an anchor tag if you're not linking to anything. From a UX standpoint it doesn't make much sense. It'll add things like an "Open link in new tab" item to the context menu that wont work. You'll have to actively prevent it from opening the link when you click it. It might still break if you open it with your mouse wheel. If you want to have an element that triggers some action within the page, then go for a button.

Comment: (Though a link would be fine if it _also_ links to something relevant. Like the Stack Exchange button on the top right of SO.)

Comment: AFAIK links should redirect, if you click on the link and something changes, but not the URL it's invalid usage and unexpected behaviour. Stackoverflow site is made so it works without JavaScript enabled, but it's really not the best practice regarding accessibility. Sometimes when I click too fast on the buttons they redirect me which is not what I want, poor UX design.